# Background Image in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm using Flash Builder 4 to create an application. I need to set an background image for the app. I've pulled through the data from XML.

I am using an `<mx:Image>` for the background-image. But I need elements to then be added inside it. How do I achieve this? I considered using Layers, but dont know how you achieve this.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I am using <mx:Image> for the background-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach: in our flex application, we have a canvas behind our primary container as in

```
<mx:Canvas id="bgImg" width="1280" height="800"
           backgroundImage="assets/background.jpg" />
<containers:FlashContainer id="mainContainer">
<!-- HBoxs, VBoxes and loads of other components -->
</containers:FlashContainer>
```

So, the other elements you're looking to add would exist within the internal container with a stationary Canvas "behind" it, which holds your image.

To get this to work in Flex 4 you need to compile with the Halo theme (instead of Spark).  We use flex builder and set the following flag under the project compiler preferences.

```
-theme=${flexlib}/themes/Halo/halo.swc
```

As in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Why would you add a Canvas just for the background instead of using a background Image on the Application tag?

Comment: Many thanks for this. Changed the theme to Halo. Works to an extent, But the background image has now been pushed to the right?

Comment: @Flextras: we used that format in Flex 3 because it gave us lots of control over the positioning and effects of the image.  We have strict requirements on the location of the background and we also add a showEffect.  So when the image loads, it fades in, which looks amazingly clean and crisp. So, overall, to answer your question using a component gave us far more control. However, as we migrate to Flex 4, we're considering revising this approach to use Spark skins.  However, that approach is not as simple as it should be.

Comment: @StuBlackett: that behavior is a function of your particular MXML document. What layout does your "parent" container have?  We use the

   **layout="absolute"**

property in our Application so when that background canvas is added, it is positioned at 0,0 and to move it, we set it's *x* and *y* properties.

Comment: @gmale where am I to set this layout="absolute" ? Does it go at the top in the <s:Application> tag at the top?

Comment: @StuBlackett: Yes. Exactly.  The application is a container whose layout can be vertical, horizontal or absolute.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've sorted it

Comment: @StuBlackett: Note: the halo version of the Application object is mx.core.Application (that is <mx:Application> as opposed to <s:Application>, which is the Spark version)

Answer (score 1):

In the Flex 3 Model, you can set a [backgroundImage](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#style:backgroundImage) on the Application tag, which should, effectively, give your whole application a background image.

In the Flex 4 Model, you need to create a custom skin class for your Application tag.  Set the skin using the [skinClass](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html#style:skinClass) style.  Since [s:Application](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/Application.html#styleSummary) extends SkinnableContainer, you should be able to use the default SkinnableContainer style as a guide for adding a background image.  The default background, I believe, is just a Rect w/ a solid fill.

Comment: Is this also possible with XML Data?

Comment: Nothing I said relates to data at all.  If your background image location is located inside an XML document; you'll have to extract it as use that source value as the backgroundImage style.

Comment: Since you added a clarification on your original post; I'll specify that the Image is not a container and you cannot put elements inside it.  If using Absolute positioning you can put other components on top of it, though.

Answer (score 0):

i m still working in flex3, so i would have used backgroundImage on the application tag, and also do set backgroundSize to 100%, these 2 properties r on the application tag,

may be some help 2 u

tc